# Why FoxPro 2.0 fails to run?

Tags: foxpro

fresh installation of FoxPro 2.0 under DOS 5 fails to run with an error message:

`EXE and OVL file do not match`

what does it mean and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by downgrading to v1.02